# What should i do to get a valid test result (string[]) instead of an WhereEnumerableIterator<string>[] for a method using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

The problem is this:

with given integers a and b, return all the possible combinations in the form

```
±1±2±3±...±a = b
```

this is my method for it

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AllCombinationsWithAAndSumOfB(int a, int b)
    {
        List<string> list= new List<string>();
        Func<string, List<string>> newList = y =>
        {
            var list = new string[2];
            list[0] = y + "+";
            list[1] = y + "-";
            return list.ToList();
        };

        Func<int, List<string>> AddingToTheLists = x =>
        {
            list = list.SelectMany(y => newList(y)).ToList();
            return list;
        };

        Func<char, string, int> CharToInt = (x, g) =>
        {
            return x == '-' ? -(g.IndexOf(x) + 1) : g.IndexOf(x) + 1;
        };

        return Enumerable.Range(1, a).SelectMany(AddingToTheLists).Where(x => x.Length == a && x.Sum(y => CharToInt(y, x)) <= b);
    }
```

Now, i'm trying to run a test. This is the test.

```
[Fact]
    public void AllCombinationsWithAAndSumOfBWork()
    {
        string[] list= { "++-", "+-+", "-+-", "--+", "---" };
        var result = AllCombinationsWithAAndSumOfB(3, 0);
        Assert.Equal(list, result);
    }
```

The problem is the result of the test:

```
Result Message: 
Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: String[] ["++-", "+-+", "-+-", "--+", "---"]
Actual:   WhereEnumerableIterator<String> []
```

What should i do to stop getting the result WhereEnumerableIterator [] ?

Comment: Try to add `ToList()`  in the end of AllCombinationsWithAAndSumOfB function

Comment: Add .ToArray() instead of .ToList()

Comment: I did both of those things, didn't help

Comment: and when i tried to get a string[] instead of an ienumerator<string>, the test result was stuck with a string[] []

Comment: `AllCombinationsWithAAndSumOfB` returns `IEnumerable<string>` (it is in the definiton). Why do you expect that to equal `string[]`? What does `Assert.Equal` actually do?

Comment: Also, can you put in some sample answers - your form doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Your method doesn't work - `list` starts out as empty, so `SelectMany` in `AddingToTheLists` is never executed, so `newList` is never called, so an empty list is eventually returned. Initializing `list` with `""` gets a closer answer, but what is `CharToInt` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you want all possible combinations of additions and subtractions for a by-one sequentially increasing ordered list, that is of `a` length, of integers that sum up to `b`.

For example: If `a = 3`, and `b = 0`, then all combinations of additions and subtractions of each of the integers in the following ordered list: `1, 2, 3` should sum to `0`.

If so, then the algorithm can be as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AllCombinationsWithAAndSumOfB(int a, int b)
{   
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, a);

    var signCombos = Enumerable
        .Range(0, Convert.ToInt32("".PadLeft(a, '1'), 2) + 1)
        .Select(e => Convert.ToString(e, 2).PadLeft(a, '0').Replace('0', '-').Replace('1', '+'));

    var calc = new DataTable();

    return signCombos.Select(
        signCombo => new 
        {
            signCombo = signCombo, 
            formula = String.Join("", signCombo.ToCharArray().Zip(numbers, (s, n) => $"{s}{n}"))
        })
        .Where(si => ((int)calc.Compute(si.formula, null)) == b)
        .Select(si => si.signCombo);
}
```

This returns

```
--+
++-
```

Because:

```
-1 -2 +3 = 0
+1 +2 -3 = 0
```